# Andorid How to get the name of the current city using coordinates

Tags: android, localization, gps, provider, city

The title of the question pretty much sums up what I want to ask. So I have the code to get the name of the current city using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` and it works like a charm. However a question popped up: "What will happen if the phone cant get the name of the city using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`?". And of course I found that phone: for some reasons LENOVO phones cant get the coordinates using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. So my question how can I make my app first to look for the coordinates to get the name of the city using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` and if the result is null to get the coordinates using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_where_am_i);   

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);       

}
```

and I get the name of the city with:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{       
    curLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    curLongitude = location.getLongitude();     

    try{
         //Get the name of the city the user is currently in base on the current latitude and Longitude
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.UK);
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(curLatitude, curLongitude,1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                StringBuilder cityName = new StringBuilder();                
                cityName.append(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                CityName = cityName.toString();                
                //Check if the user is in allowed cities                   
            }            

        }
    catch(IOException ex)
         {
          ex.printStackTrace();
         }

}
```

Comment: visit http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/convert-celllocation-to-real-location.html  and  http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-get-location-without-gps-using.html  may help you

Comment: [This link](http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example) might be helpful to you. Try `GPSTracker` for getting `lat` and `lng` instead of loaction manager

Comment: but what I want is to switch between GPS and NETWORK provider

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter:

1. getPremises();
2. getSubAdminArea();
   3.getSubLocality();

[If you want in detail you should prefer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)

Comment: that is great but how will this help me switch between providers?

Comment: This your own codding way, I think you should use method and call your onLocationChanged() for both provider.

Answer (score 0):

When location update is requested by a provider it is not guaranteed to return location update. The method onLocationChanged() is only called when location is changed. If u'll use Network_provider to get location update then it will take much time to return location update. In this case u may start a timer and when it expires u may get location update from GPS_provider. Otherwise just simple do below

```
myLocObj =  new MyLocationListener();
manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

nw = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if( nw ){
    Toast.makeText(BasicArchitectActivity.this, "fetching from NW", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocObj);
}

gps = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if( gps ){
    Toast.makeText(BasicArchitectActivity.this, "fetching from GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocObj);
}


if(!gps && !nw){
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Please enable GPS and Network positioning in your Settings ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

here's the location listener

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    double currentlat, currentlng;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location != null){

            currentlat = location.getLatitude();
            currentlng = location.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(BasicArchitectActivity.this, "Current location \nlat= " +currentlat+",  lng= " + currentlng , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```